# EXC_BAD_ACCESS during a segue?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a problem where I'm getting a bad access code for my app running iOS 6. I'm currently segueing to another `navigationBar` based `view`, and getting the bad access code inside the class I'm segueing to (during the segue!). The trace goes back to the first thing I release inside of Dealloc (which is just a standard `UILabel`).

Is this a possible problem with iOS 6? I thought `dealloc` was deprecated starting in iOS 6? Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: `dealloc` is not deprecated. Under ARC, you can still use `dealloc`, you just don't make an explicit call to `[super dealloc]`. This has nothing to do with any specific version of iOS.

Comment: Is leaving [super dealloc] in the dealloc method (while not using arc) still acceptable?

Comment: If you are not using ARC then calling `[super dealloc]` is required, not just acceptable.

Comment: If you are not using ARC then perhaps you are over-releasing your view controller resulting in `dealloc` being called prematurely.

Comment: I'm not sure...Dealloc gets called when I'm segueing to it for the very first time and I've never loaded it before. Could print statements cause a problem in dealloc?? I just moved a print statement to the end of dealloc and it didn't crash this time, but it was still called.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use release with ARC. You probably don't even need to override dealloc.

Comment: first - why not? second, sounds like you're releasing an object twice. exactly what ARC is helping you avoid.